# ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a field to the table or update it if it exists. But the value of my sql key is 'ID' and the value that should be checked is 'metakey'.
Therefore, I can not use 'ON DUPLICATE KEY' code.
what should I do?

Comment: Put a unique index on `metakey`? Make `metakey` the PK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the fine manual:

[image]

> If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value *in a UNIQUE index* or PRIMARY KEY

So, it matters not that `metakey` is not the PK; it just needs a unique index and then you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY